# List all directories that do NOT have a file with a given file name inside

Tags: files, directory

How would I go into listing all directories that do **not** have a file with a given file name inside? e.g. given this tree

```
/
  /a
     README
     file001
     file002
  /b
     README
     file001
  /c
     file003
```

I want to list the directories that do **not** have a file named `README`, in this case it would be directory `/c`. How would I do that? I can't think of any syntax using e.g. `find`.

Comment: Shame oh shame you didn't even search: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file

Comment: I didn't think of the right keywords when searching, probably.

Comment: I'm just bust'in your chops. I've been there many many times where I couldn't think of the right word to search for something 8-).

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming a `find` implementation like GNU `find` that accepts a `{}` embedded in an argument to `-exec`:

```
$ find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/README' \; -print
```

or, without the problematic embedding:

```
$ find . -type d ! -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1"/README' sh {} \; -print
```

#### Example

Here directories 1/1 through 5/5 have a README, the other dirs are empty.

```
$ tree 
.
|-- 1
|   `-- 1
|       `-- README
|-- 10
|   `-- 10
|-- 2
|   `-- 2
|       `-- README
|-- 3
|   `-- 3
|       `-- README
|-- 4
|   `-- 4
|       `-- README
|-- 5
|   `-- 5
|       `-- README
|-- 6
|   `-- 6
|-- 7
|   `-- 7
|-- 8
|   `-- 8
`-- 9
    `-- 9
```

Now when we run this version of our `find` command:

```
$ find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/README' \; -print
.
./10
./10/10
./7
./7/7
./9
./9/9
./6
./6/6
./5
./8
./8/8
./4
./1
./3
./2
```

#### References

- [Exclude directories in find that don't contain a specific filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225270/exclude-directories-in-find-that-dont-contain-a-specific-filename)

Comment: How to modify the command to search for sub directories that dont have a specific file extension (say *.txt). Modifying README with *.txt doesnt seem to work

Comment: @WanderingMind - if you have a new question please ask it as a new one on the site ;-)

Comment: What does the `\!` do? I'm having trouble googling that bit

Answer (score 8):

No need for `find`. Just use the shell:

```
for d in */; do [ -f "$d"README ] || printf '%s\n' "$d"; done
c/
```

If you need it to be recursive, you can use (for `bash`, `zsh` can do this by default, use `set -o globstar` in `ksh93`):

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/; do [ -f "$d"README ] || printf '%s\n' "$d"; done
```

(note that dot-files are excluded by default).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-exec` option of `find` to check for the file, and then print all results for which the check fails.

```
find /path/to/base -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec test -e {}/README \; -o -print
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` and [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (`e`*string*):

```
print -rl -- *(/e_'[[ ! -f $REPLY/README ]]'_)
```

or

```
print -rl -- *(/^e_'[[ -f $REPLY/README ]]'_)
```

add `D` to include hidden directories:

```
print -rl -- *(D/e_'[[ ! -f $REPLY/README ]]'_)
```

`/` selects only directories and `e_'[[ ! -f $REPLY/README ]]'_` further selects only the directory names for which the shell code between the quotes returns `true`, that is for each directory name (`$REPLY`) that the glob `*(/)` expands to, it runs `[[ ! -f $REPLY/README ]]` and keeps the name of the directory if the result is `true`.
The second form `^e_'.....'_` uses the same glob qualifier, negated (but this time the conditional expression isn't negated: `[[ -f $REPLY/README ]]`).

---

The above will only return directory names in the current directory.
If you want to search recursively (again, to include hidden directories add the `D` qualifier):

```
print -rl ./**/*(/e_'[[ ! -f $REPLY/README ]]'_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Portably, you could do:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    [ -f "$dir/README" ] || printf "%s\n" "$dir"
  done' sh '{}' +
```

`[ -f file ]` tests if the file *exists* **and** is confirmed to be a regular file (after symlink resolution).

If you wanted to test that it exists only (as an entry in that directory), regardless of its type, you'd need: `[ -e file ] || [ -L file ]`, though note that you need search permission to the directory to perform those tests. You may want to add some `[ -x "$dir" ]` tests to account for those cases like:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    if [ -x "$dir" ]; then
      [ -f "$dir/README" ] || printf "%s\n" "$dir"
    else
      printf >&2 "Cannot tell for \"%s\"\n" "$dir"
    fi
  done' sh '{}' +
```

Or to avoid the race condition, with `zsh`:

```
find . -type d -exec zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/system
  for dir do
    ERRNO=0
    if [ ! -f "$dir/README" ]; then
      if [ "$errnos[ERRNO]" = ENOENT ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$dir"
      else
        syserror -p "ERROR: $dir/README: "
      fi
    fi
  done' zsh '{}' +
```

See also [How do I tell if a regular file does not exist in Bash?](//stackoverflow.com/a/40046642) on SO.