# Find files in directory with paired names

Tags: shell-script, files, find, directory

I'm running tests of a variable-size-and-contents test set. Data files are added and removed frequently. I'm looking for an automated way of gathering a file list.

All files are in subdirectories of `D`; I need the full directory and name added to a text file. However, I only need those files that have a "paired" file, which has the same filename but a different extension (so... different filename, but in a structured way). So, if there is a `MyFileName.A` and `MyFileName.B`, then I want `D/.../MyFileName` added to the file list.

There are `.A` files without `.B` files, but no `.B` files without `.A` files. If a `.A` has a `.B` file, then both files are in the same directory.

Any advice?

Comment: `ls D/*.B | sed 's/\.B$//' > file_list.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If none of the filenames contain any newlines, you can do:

```
find D -type f \( -name '*.A' -o -name '*.B' \) |
  sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' |
  sort |
  uniq -d >paired_files
```

This should work in the more general case where there are `.B` files without `.A` files.

To handle any filename using recent GNU tools:

```
find D -type f \( -name '*.A' -o -name '*.B' \) -print0 |
  sed -z 's/\.[^.]*$//' |
  sort -z |
  uniq -dz |
  tr '\0' '\n' >paired_files
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Flagged this as the answer as well as richard's, because this one generally applicable whereas richard's uses the very obvious property of *if B then A*

Answer (score 5):

If you statement is true “there are no .B files without .A files.”, then get a list of .B files and remove the extension.

```
find $directory-to-search -name "*.B" | sed -r -e "s~(.*)\.B~\1~g"
```

Comment: Note that `-r` to enable extended expressions is not standardised. GNU `sed` uses it but OSX `sed` uses `-E` instead. Others may not implement extended expressions at all.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. I guess that's why you should reexamine your assumptions when the problem changes.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl mydir/**/*.A(.e_'REPLY=$REPLY:r; [[ -f $REPLY.B ]]'_)
```

`:r` removes the extension, so if the content of `$REPLY` was `mydir/somedir/somefile.A` after running `REPLY=$REPLY:r` its content becomes `mydir/somedir/somefile`;
the rest is similar to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224918).