# copying sub-directories not containing a specific file into another directory

Tags: find, directory, xargs

I have a directory named `dir1` which has about 800 sub-directories named `disp-001, disp-002, ... disp-800`. I get the list of sub-directories that does not contain a file `stdout` based on solution given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/list-all-directories-that-do-not-have-a-file-with-a-given-file-name-inside) as

```
$ find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/stdout' \; -print
```

I would now like to copy the sub-directories that do not contain the file into another directory dir2. I use xargs to accomplish this as

```
$ find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/stdout' \; -print |xargs -I cp -r {} ../dir2
```

However this throws me an error `xargs: {}: No such file or directory`

How can I copy these sub-directories to another directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `xargs`; `find` can handle that:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/stdout' \; -exec echo cp -r '{}' ../dir2 \;
```

or with a modern version of `find`, `\+` will make `find` do an `xargs`-like thing (or, the horror, 800 forks!)

- You need `-mindepth 1` to exclude the `./` folder which otherwise would
  copy all the sub-directories.
- The `-exec` command contains a debug `echo` option to see the process to be carried out before you perform the copy

Comment: They are directories so I added `-r` after `cp`. It prints the correct output but the copy does not seem to happen. Can you verify if it works for you?

Comment: There's a debugging `echo`, which is handy to verify in advance how you're about to destroy your filesystem.

Comment: My bad. There is an issue, since the output also produces the folder `./ ` which means it will perform `cp -r ./ ../dir2` which in turn will copy all the sub-folders irrespective of presence of the file

Comment: `-mindepth 1` should exclude `./`

Comment: Great that works.