# Identify sub-directories that do not contain a specific string in a specific file

Tags: grep, find, directory, search, string

I have a directory named `dir1` which has about 800 sub-directories named `disp-001, disp-002, ... disp-800`. I need to find sub-directories that

- either do not contain a file `stdout` or
- if they do, that file does not contain a particular string `str1`.

Identifying sub-directories that do not contain the file is answered in  [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/list-all-directories-that-do-not-have-a-file-with-a-given-file-name-inside)

```
$ find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/stdout' \; -print
```

However if I try to include grep in the above command, it does not work

```
 $ find . -type d \! -exec test -e 'grep str1 {}/stdout' \; -print
```

How can I include the string search to return me the directory of interest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt any of the solutions there, e.g.

- use `( -exec` *or* `-exec )` with *slm*'s or *patrick*'s solutions (the second `exec` is executed only if the first one returns `false`, `-print` is executed only if one of them returns `true`):

  ```
  find . -type d \( ! -exec test -f '{}/stdout' \; -o ! -exec grep -q str1 '{}/stdout' \; \) -print
  ```

  or even shorter as suggested by *Costas*:

  ```
  find . -type d \! -exec grep -q 'str1' {}/stdout 2>/dev/null \; -print
  ```
- use a condition with *terdon*'s solution:

  ```
  for d in **/
  do
    if [[ ! -f "$d"stdout ]] then
      printf '%s\n' "$d"
    else
      grep -q str1 "$d"stdout || printf '%s\n' "$d"
    fi
  done
  ```
- or, with `zsh`:

  ```
  print -rl **/*(/e_'[[ ! -f $REPLY/stdout ]] || ! grep -q str1 $REPLY/stdout'_)
  ```

Comment: You can avoid extra test `find . -type d \! -exec grep -q 'str1' {}/stdout 2>/dev/null \; -print`

Comment: @Costas - you're right, I misunderstood the question... I'll edit my answer... Thanks for the heads-up !

Answer (score 2):

To get that list just use `grep`:

```
grep -L str1 dir-*/stdout
```

Where:

- `-L` gives only the file without a match.
- `str1` is the string you want to search.
- And if your files are in the same depth you can use simple wildcards.

  - If not, use the `-r` flag of `grep` to search recusively in the directories.

---

To continue that and work on that list you could pipe it nullbyte-delimited (`grep`s `-Z`) to a while loop:

```
grep -LZ str1 dir-*/stdout | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  echo "${f%%/*}" # gives the directory name
done
```